# Create new array with two columns from old array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I have an array as follows:

```
items = [
{"year": 2010, "month": 11, "day":23}
{"year": 2009, "month": 10, "day":15}
{"year": 2009, "month": 10, "day":10} //added after my edit below
]
```

I would like to create a new array with only 2 of the columns like this:

```
newArarry = [
{"year": 2010, "month": 11}
{"year": 2009, "month": 10}
]
```

Right now Im trying with .map() and its not working:

```
const newArray = [];
newArray.map({
    year: items.year,
    month: items.month
});
```

**EDIT**

After following one of the answers below, I realized I forgot to mention that I would also need to filter the result to be only unique rows. Now that I am only selecting the year and month columns, I am getting multiple duplicate rows

Comment: do the map on the Items and it will return to you the new array.

Comment: @MennyMez see my updated answer to account for your edit.

Answer (score 7):

> Right now Im trying with .map() and its not working

- Because newArray is having length `0` and you're trying to map on it
- map accepts a callback but you're passing object
- Not assigning output of map to any variable

```js
let items = [{"year": 2010, "month": 11, "day":23},{"year": 2009, "month": 10, "day":15}]

let final = items.map(({day,...rest}) => ({...rest}))

console.log(final)
```

Answer (score 6):

You are not calling [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) correctly:

1. You need to call in on the *source* array: `items`.
2. You need to provide a *function* as an argument.
3. `Array#map` returns a new array that is the result of the function being executed against each member of the original array.

```js
items = [
{"year": 2010, "month": 11, "day":23},
{"year": 2009, "month": 10, "day":15}
]

const newArray = items.map(item => ({
    year: item.year,
    month: item.month
}));

console.log(newArray)
```

A *mapping* operation transforms from A to B - in this case from `{"year": 2010, "month": 11, "day":23}` to `{ "year": 2010, "month": 11 }`. Running a `.map` on an array gives you the result of the mapping operation.

Comment: Thanks, I am currently using this method. However, I am now getting duplicate rows. Is there a way to only select unique rows (my items array is much larger than whats in my question)

Comment: @Mennyg have a look [at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9229821/3689450)

Answer (score 5):

Array's `.map()` method accepts a callback whose returned value will be used to construct new array. Mistakenly you are passing it an object instead of a function. To fix this you can use `.map()` with some Object Destructuring:

```js
const items = [
  {"year": 2010, "month": 11, "day":23},
  {"year": 2009, "month": 10, "day":15}
];

const result = items.map(({ year, month }) => ({year, month}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 3):

`Array.map()` expects a callback as the first parameter, it must also be called on the original array - otherwise you're essentially iterating over an empty array.

```
var newArray = items.map(function (item) {
    return {
        year: item.year,
        month: item.month
    };
});
```

---

**Update**

In order to make sure your array only contains unique values, rather than mapping and filtering, you could do something similar to the following:

```
var items = [
    {year: 2010, month: 11, day: 23},
    {year: 2009, month: 10, day: 15},
    {year: 2009, month: 10, day: 10}
];

var newArray = [];

items.forEach(function (item) {
    var index = newArray.findIndex(function (newItem) {
        return newItem.year === item.year && newItem.month === item.month;
    });

    if (index === -1) {
        newArray.push({ year: item.year, month: item.month });
    }
});

console.log(newArray); // [{ year: 2010, month: 11 }, { year: 2009, month: 10 }]
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not using `map` correctly - you can also simplify with rest, spread, and destructuring:

```js
const items = [{"year": 2010, "month": 11, "day":23},{"year": 2009, "month": 10, "day":15}];
const newArray = items.map(({ day, ...res }) => ({ ...res }));
console.log(newArray);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct your items array, Array with multiple elements/values must be comma separated

```js
var items = [{"year": 2010, "month": 11, "day":23},
               {"year": 2009, "month": 10, "day":15}]
                    const newArray = [];
                    items.map(i=>{
                    newArray.push({year: i.year, month: i.month});
                    });
                  console.log(newArray);
```